# Weird behaviour for String.substring(5).replace("", "") // empty string

Tags: java, android, string, replace, substring

#### Note: i am having this problem on my Android project, in Eclipse.

Here is my code:

```
    String str = "just_a_string";
    System.out.println("]" + str + "[");
    System.out.println("]" + str.replace("", "") + "[");
    System.out.println("]" + str.substring(5) + "[");
    System.out.println("]" + str.substring(5).replace("", "") + "[");
    System.out.println("]" + str.substring(3, 8) + "[");
    System.out.println("]" + str.substring(3, 8).replace("", "") + "[");
    System.out.println("]" + "sdajndan".substring(5).replace("", "") + "[");
```

and here is the output

```
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]just_a_string[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]just_a_string[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]a_string[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]a_s[      **
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]t_a_s[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]t_[       **
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ][         **
```

Obviously, the lines marked with ** are unexpected.

Can someone please explain? Thanks very much for any input!!

Comment: That code doesn't produce that output. It produces this output (http://pastie.org/7822100): `]just_a_string[ // ]just_a_string[ // ]a_string[ // ]a_string[ // ]t_a_s[ // ]t_a_s[ // ]dan[`

Comment: Maybe related with OS/JVM? It works for me too :-)

Comment: Your question would be easier to read if you remove all the code *except* the outputs you find odd.

Comment: @dunadar: If it output what the OP says it does, it would be a serious bug, as what is being quoted is very much at variance with the API documentation. :-)

Comment: Oops... it keeps producing that erroneous output in my Eclipse. I am developing Android apps on it. In fact i have opened a new project and tested for those lines only. Thanks you guys. I will keep you guys updated.

Comment: Well.. i have tried on my Eclipse, with a **Java** project. It gives the expected correct output. But, in the **Android** project. The output is weird. (i am going to check the version of Java of them respectively.)

Comment: why exactly do you use .replace("", "") ?

Comment: For my **Java** project, `System.getProperty("java.version")` gives `1.7.0_21`. For the **Android** project, the version is N/A, as said [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29). But i believe it is 1.6, and Android can't be 1.7 (as said in the setting `Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level`).

Comment: Btw i am messing up will the _compiler version_ and the _running version_. In my **Java** project, i have set 1.6 in `Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level` also. But there is a warning saying i have only 1.7 JRE. i guess i have to install JRE 1.6? i gtg now and will be back to this issue in an hour or two. Thanks you guys again!!!

Comment: @Dropout, i know it doesn't really make sense. But i am developing a library and i got to handle varies user inputs.

Comment: i have just installed JRE 1.6 and it prints `1.6.0_43`. It gives the correct results. i am now downloading JRE 1.5. And will try on a different Android device.

Comment: When i set my **Android** project to 1.7, Eclipse says no by `Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead.` And that piece of code halt my another Android phone after printing the first line.

Comment: **Java** `1.5.0_22` also gives correct results. But in **Android**, JRE 1.5 and 1.6 are both giving that weird result on one of my phone, and halt another one.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your efforts so far. **i have found the bug**. And its on [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475317/android-bug-string-substring5-replace-empty-string). Would some moderators move our discussions here to [that thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475317/android-bug-string-substring5-replace-empty-string), as it is almost a complete duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @Dropout, `.replace("", "")` doesn't make sense. But `.replace("", "-")` **does**. And `.replace("", "-")` will cause the same issue as mentioned.