# Android Bug? : String.substring(5).replace(“”, “”) // empty string

Tags: java, android, string, substring, str-replace

Here is my code:

```
String str = "just_a_string";
System.out.println("]" + str + "[");
System.out.println("]" + str.replace("", "") + "[");
System.out.println("]" + str.substring(5) + "[");
System.out.println("]" + str.substring(5).replace("", "") + "[");
System.out.println("]" + str.substring(3, 8) + "[");
System.out.println("]" + str.substring(3, 8).replace("", "") + "[");
System.out.println("]" + "sdajndan".substring(5).replace("", "") + "[");
```

and here is the output

```
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]just_a_string[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]just_a_string[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]a_string[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]a_s[      **
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]t_a_s[
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ]t_[       **
05-09 19:09:20.570: I/System.out(23801): ][         **
```

Obviously, the lines marked with ** are unexpected.

This issue happens to my Android phone A (LG P920 Optimus 3D, Android 2.3.3). While i test on my Android phone B (LG E720 Optimus Chic, Android 2.2), it halts. i guess it runs into an infinite loop.

i have tested on both phones, with Java `1.5` and `1.6`. Both result in the same behaviour respectively.

i have also tested on my same Eclipse with a **Java** project, for `1.5`, `1.6`, and `1.7`. All of their outputs are correct, as expected.

i wonder this might be a device specific issue of implementing `String.replace(“”, “”)` against the String's [backing array](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#backing_array).

Could you please help me to test in your devices?

Could anyone please provide me the Android source code of the `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` method? (like what in [docjar](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28CharSequence,%20CharSequence%29))

Thanks a lot!

---

i have modified the code a bit, so it can also display on the Android device. (It is just the same code anyway).

Tested on both my phone A and phone B. Behaviours are still the same, as mentioned above.

```
package com.example.testprojectnew;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String output_text = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String str = "just_a_string";
        process("1]" + str + "[");
        process("2]" + str.replace("", "") + "[");
        process("3]" + str.substring(5) + "[");
        process("4]" + str.substring(5).replace("", "") + "[");
        process("5]" + str.substring(3, 8) + "[");
        process("6]" + str.substring(3, 8).replace("", "") + "[");
        process("7]" + "sdajndan".substring(5).replace("", "") + "[");

        output_text = output_text.concat("\n\nLines (1 & 2), (3 & 4), (5 & 6), should be the same.");

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_string)).setText(output_text);
    }
    private void process(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
        output_text = output_text.concat(str).concat("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to do lots of string manipulations, there is a class called StringBuilder better suited for that purpose. (StringBuffer if the strings need to be manipulated by different threads, StringBuilder if not)

Comment: Hmm... thanks for suggestion. But that's just a `substring()` followed by a `replace()`. Not really that a lot to create a `StringBuilder`, i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Bingo! i have found the bug!

Thanks @izht for providing the link of the [source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/java/lang/String.java.htm). i have located the bug regarding this problem.

This only happens when the String's [backing array](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#backing_array) is having a different (longer) value than the actual String. In particular, when the `String.offset` (private variable) is larger than zero.

Here's the fix:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    if (target == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("target == null");
    }
    if (replacement == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("replacement == null");
    }

    String targetString = target.toString();
    int matchStart = indexOf(targetString, 0);
    if (matchStart == -1) {
        // If there's nothing to replace, return the original string untouched.
        return this;
    }

    String replacementString = replacement.toString();

    // The empty target matches at the start and end and between each character.
    int targetLength = targetString.length();
    if (targetLength == 0) {
        int resultLength = (count + 2) * replacementString.length();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(resultLength);
        result.append(replacementString);
//        for (int i = offset; i < count; ++i) {             // original, bug
        for (int i = offset; i < (count + offset); ++i) {    // fix
            result.append(value[i]);
            result.append(replacementString);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(count);
    int searchStart = 0;
    do {
        // Copy characters before the match...
        result.append(value, offset + searchStart, matchStart - searchStart);
        // Insert the replacement...
        result.append(replacementString);
        // And skip over the match...
        searchStart = matchStart + targetLength;
    } while ((matchStart = indexOf(targetString, searchStart)) != -1);
    // Copy any trailing chars...
    result.append(value, offset + searchStart, count - searchStart);
    return result.toString();
}
```

i am not sure why Android has to alter (and altered wrongly) the `replace()` in this way. The original Java implementation doesn't have this issue.

By-the-way, **what's now?** What can i do with it? (other than using `replace()` with extra care, or throw away my Android phones :-/)

---

Btw i m quite sure my LG E720 Optimus Chic (Android 2.2) is using a different source code than [that one](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/java/lang/String.java.htm). It keeps halting (suspect infinite looping) upon `String.replace()` with an *empty* target string. Lately i found it throws this error message:

```
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:157)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:1497)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at com.example.testprojectnew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
05-10 16:41:13.155: E/AndroidRuntime(9384):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

At a second thought, if that for-loop thingy *is* the bug. It should be a compile time issue. Why would it act differently in different phones (different versions of Android)?

---

## Complete Workaround

Got [an update](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55129#c5) from Google, that they have patched it, and will correct it [in the future release](https://android-review.googlesource.com/58393).

Meanwhile, i have written a patched method, based on [their code](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/58393/1/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java):

*(This is necessary because (1) we still have to wait for the correct release, (2) we need to take care of devices that didnt make that fixed update)*

```
/** Patch for the String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement),
 *  because the original is buggy when CharSequence target is empty, i.e. "".
 *  Patched by Google Android: https://android-review.googlesource.com/58393
 */
public static String replacePatched(final String string, final CharSequence target, final CharSequence replacement) {
    if (target == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("target == null");
    }
    if (replacement == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("replacement == null");
    }

    final String targetString = target.toString();
    int matchStart = string.indexOf(targetString, 0);
    if (matchStart == -1) {
        // If there's nothing to replace, return the original string untouched.
        return new String(string);
    }

    final char[] value = string.toCharArray();                              // required in patch
    final int count = value.length;                                         // required in patch

    final String replacementString = replacement.toString();

    // The empty target matches at the start and end and between each character.
    if (targetString.length() == 0) {
        // The result contains the original 'count' characters, a copy of the
        // replacement string before every one of those characters, and a final
        // copy of the replacement string at the end.
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(count + (count + 1) * replacementString.length());
        result.append(replacementString);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            result.append(value[i]);
            result.append(replacementString);
        }
        return new String(result);      // StringBuilder.toString() does not give exact length
    }

    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(count);
    int searchStart = 0;
    do {
        // Copy characters before the match...
        result.append(value, searchStart, matchStart - searchStart);
        // Insert the replacement...
        result.append(replacementString);
        // And skip over the match...
        searchStart = matchStart + targetString.length();
    } while ((matchStart = string.indexOf(targetString, searchStart)) != -1);
    // Copy any trailing chars...
    result.append(value, searchStart, count - searchStart);
    return new String(result);          // StringBuilder.toString() does not give exact length
}
```

The verbose version:

```
/** Patch for the String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement),
 *  because the original is buggy when CharSequence target is empty, i.e. "".
 *  Patched by Google Android: https://android-review.googlesource.com/58393
 */
public static String replacePatched(final String string, final CharSequence target, final CharSequence replacement) {
    if (target == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("target == null");
    }
    if (replacement == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("replacement == null");
    }

//    String targetString = target.toString();                                    // original
    final String targetString = target.toString();
//    int matchStart = indexOf(targetString, 0);                                  // original
    int matchStart = string.indexOf(targetString, 0);
    if (matchStart == -1) {
        // If there's nothing to replace, return the original string untouched.
//        return this;                                                            // original
        return new String(string);
    }

    final char[] value = string.toCharArray();                              // required in patch
    final int count = value.length;                                         // required in patch

//    String replacementString = replacement.toString();                          // original
    final String replacementString = replacement.toString();

    // The empty target matches at the start and end and between each character.
//    int targetLength = targetString.length();                                   // original
//    if (targetLength == 0) {                                                    // original
    if (targetString.length() == 0) {
//        int resultLength = (count + 2) * replacementString.length();            // original
//        // The result contains the original 'count' characters, a copy of the
//        // replacement string before every one of those characters, and a final
//        // copy of the replacement string at the end.
//        int resultLength = count + (count + 1) * replacementString.length();    // patched by Google Android
//        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(resultLength);                 // original
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(count + (count + 1) * replacementString.length());
        result.append(replacementString);
//        for (int i = offset; i < count; ++i) {                                  // original
//        int end = offset + count;                                               // patched by Google Android
//        for (int i = offset; i != end; ++i) {                                   // patched by Google Android
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            result.append(value[i]);
            result.append(replacementString);
        }
//        return result.toString();                                               // original
        return new String(result);      // StringBuilder.toString() does not give exact length
    }

//    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(count);                            // original
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(count);
    int searchStart = 0;
    do {
        // Copy characters before the match...
//        result.append(value, offset + searchStart, matchStart - searchStart);   // original
        result.append(value, searchStart, matchStart - searchStart);
        // Insert the replacement...
        result.append(replacementString);
        // And skip over the match...
//        searchStart = matchStart + targetLength;                                // original
        searchStart = matchStart + targetString.length();
//    } while ((matchStart = indexOf(targetString, searchStart)) != -1);          // original
    } while ((matchStart = string.indexOf(targetString, searchStart)) != -1);
    // Copy any trailing chars...
//    result.append(value, offset + searchStart, count - searchStart);            // original
    result.append(value, searchStart, count - searchStart);
//    return result.toString();                                                   // original
    return new String(result);          // StringBuilder.toString() does not give exact length
}
```

Comment: Just tested on my sister's Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2), the same bug occurs, with the same behaviour as my LG Optimus 3D (Android 2.3.3).