# Why same piece of (simple) Java code behaves very differently on different Android devices?

Tags: android, compiler-construction, java, str-replace

Why same piece of (simple) Java code behaves very differently on different Android devices?

That simple piece of code is just the use of `String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` with `target == ""`:

```
package com.example.stringreplacetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String str = "just_a_string";

        System.out.println(str.replace("", "-"));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(str.replace("", "-"));
    }
}
```

It produces `-j-u-s-t-_-a-_-s-t-r-i-n-g-` on my LG Optimus 3D P920 (Android 2.3.3), and my sister's Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2)*, and i guess on most of your devices as well.*

But it halts (a suspect of infinite looping) on my LG Optimus Chic (Android 2.2).

The old LG Optimus Chic and Android 2.2 may be buggy. (`String.replace()` indeed has [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475317/android-bug-string-substring5-replace-empty-string).) But [the piece of code](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/58393/1/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java) in `String.replace()` is relatively simple - "simple" means no dynamic binding, no Threads, etc...

Isn't [that piece of code](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/58393/1/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java) should be finalised during compile time? How does Java compiler work (as i know Java is a cross-platform language, it may work differently)?

P.S. to ensure it is the same piece of compiled code, i actually transferred the compiled `.apk` by USB to my Android phones, rather than using Eclipse to RUN them directly in the devices.

---

i have found the source code of Android 2.2 Froyo:

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/froyo-release/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java

It *does* cause infinite looping when `target.length == 0` (because in the `do-while loop`, `string.indexOf("", tail)` will *never* return `-1`).

Doubts has been cleared a bit. But...

### i still don't know why different versions of `String` class is loaded, upon running in different devices. Is it this is what meant to be *cross-platform*?

Comment: Would it be a case that the `String.replace()` method in Android 2.2 loads a library (e.g. Regex pattern?) that makes this difference? Btw [where can i get the source of Android 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559792/where-can-i-browse-the-android-2-2-froyo-source-of-java-lang-string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me close this question.

i could not find concrete documentary references. But after my repeated trials, and a few researches of the "differences between Java vs C compiler". Yes, this is the Java behaviour - **compile once, run everywhere** (& debug everywhere).

This is why we need the Java VM. This is why Java compiles faster than C/C++. This is why Java runs slower than C/C++.

(i guess) While Java compiles, it only records the class signatures. Upon running on VM, it matches those signatures with the real implementations of the corresponding classes, compile them into machine codes just-in-time. That is why Java can **compile once, run on different machines**, because different VMs have their own implementations of the classes. This also lead to the problem that, if there is a bug in a certain version, the programmer can do *nothing* about it. It is because the actual buggy implementation is at the client side where the end-user is running the program. We need to wait the user to update their own VM.

P.S. in fact we can re-invent the wheel, re-write our own classes. So those classes will be attached into the deployed program.