# Where can i browse the Android 2.2 Froyo source of java.lang.String?

Tags: android, string, git, open-source, android-source

I would like to browse it online.

The official Google one is always preferred.

In particular, i want to access

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/froyo/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java

But as you can see in [the list here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/), only `gingerbread` and later releases are available.

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/gingerbread/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java

If there is *really* nowhere to browse it online, attach the code stub of `public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` and related methods, is also appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has the right tag and class name: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/android-2.2_r1/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/String.java.

Comment: Thanks @Joe!! This is exactly what i was looking for! So i can now continue my work :-)