# Matcher.replaceAll() and String.replaceAll() don't seem to work on Galaxy S 6

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to remove some characters from a string. Currently I'm trying to remove ' ' (space) and '-' (hyphen). I have tried two ways. Both of them work on a Nexus 5X with Android N Beta. None of them work on a Samsung Galaxy S 6 with Android M.

First approach:

```
String normalizedNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[ -]", "");
```

Second approach:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ -]");
String normalizedNumber = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber).replaceAll("");
```

How can such basic classes give different results? What am I doing wrong?

Proof (debugger screenshots, taken on different PCs, that's why the are styled different):

Here is Nexus

[image: Nexus]
Here is Samsung

[image: Samsung]

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the code, program flow and input are the same across all devices?

Comment: This seems very unlikely. Can you prove this is happening?.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 same code as I install them on both devices using Android Studio on my desk. Same program flow, this is called only once and I put a breakpoint right after.

Comment: @shmosel even if I stop the debugger with a breakpoint and manually evaluate several expressions, I get the same results (it seems the expressions are evaluated on the device by Android Studio). Would you need a screenshot to believe me?

Comment: @shmosel also take into account that there have been bugs related to such basic classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475317/android-bug-string-substring5-replace-empty-string Maybe this is another instace that's patched in AOSP but not in Samsung code?

Comment: @nvn - if your requirement is only to remove ' ' and '-'   you can modify your approach-1  like this    phoneNumber.replace(" ","").replace("-","")  Hope it should give same result in any environment since it does'nt go with finding regex pattern and replace. In the above two approaches replaceAll will go with pattern match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistery solved. When using `String.charAt()` to analize the string, it turns out that the spaces weren't simple spaces after all, but "[non breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)" (code 160). Changing the code to remove all whitespace fixed it:

```
String normalizedNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[\\s-]", "");
```

The code was giving different results on different phones, because the numbers came from the contact picker Intent. It seems Samgung phones store the spaces in numbers different than Nexus phones.

Thanks everyone for your help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try with Approach 1 with the below modification:

```
String normalizedNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ","").replace("-","");
```

Hope this should work in any environment as its a direct character replacement approach where as replaceAll is always a compiled pattern approach of matching the characters

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work, thanks. I will try this on Monday, as the Samsung phone is my co-worker's, not mine.